# Flutter doesn't build iOS app using Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to add Firebase Cloud Firestore functionalities to my test Flutter app but encountering problem when trying to build an app/run in debug.

I have followed official Flutter video how to add Firebase for iOS (register app, download .plist - add it inside Xcode). Of course I also added firestore dependancy to pubspec.

When I try to run my app, all I get in debug console is:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XS in debug mode...
```

And it stays in that mode forever.

I have tried to remove Firestore from dependancies and after that my app ran without any problems.

Flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-SI)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/zanfras/Developer/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/zanfras/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3.5)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 33.3.2
    • Dart plugin version 183.5912.23

[✓] VS Code (version 1.32.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Žan’s iPhone • 00008020-001D48660C28002E • ios • iOS 12.1.4

• No issues found!
```

GitHub link to sample project: https://github.com/frasza/flutter-firebase-test

Flutter run -v log:
https://pastebin.com/Q3jTU3jN

Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Comment: In my case adding below line in pod file worked
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git'=> '8.0.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `flutter run -v` and leaving it to run for few minutes, build was successful. Even tho it took almost 10 minutes.

Comment: Firestore uses grpccpp under the hood which requires quite a lot of compilation time. This leads to minutes of extra build time. Feel free to vote on this issue. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/349